# When a d3.behavior.zoom event is triggered programatically, how do you set inital values for translate and scale?

Tags: d3.js, zooming

The squares in the example below are part of an SVG group that has an initial translate and scale set.

Clicking on a square initiates a zoom transition. But the intial values set by the transition are different from my defaults, as made obvious by the jarring start to this transition.

How can I set initial values for translate and scale on a zoom transition that I initiate programatically?

```js
var svg = d3.select("#main");

svg.append("rect").attr({"x":0,"y":0,"height":100,"width":100,"fill":"red"})
svg.append("rect").attr({"x":100,"y":100,"height":100,"width":100,"fill":"blue"})
svg.append("rect").attr({"x":0,"y":100,"height":100,"width":100,"fill":"green"})
svg.append("rect").attr({"x":100,"y":0,"height":100,"width":100,"fill":"yellow"})

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom",function(){
  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale;
  console.log(s)
  
  svg.attr("transform","translate("+t[0]+","+t[1]+") scale("+s+")")
  
}).scaleExtent([1,10]).scale(1).translate([0,0])

d3.select("svg").call(zoom)

d3.selectAll("rect").on("mousedown",function(){
  var scale = Math.random()*3;
  var translate = [Math.random()*200,Math.random()*200]
  zoom.scale(scale);
  zoom.translate(translate);
  
  //new transition
  var T = svg.transition().duration(5000)
  zoom.event(T);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<p style="font-weight:bold">When a zoom is triggered programatically, how do you set inital values for translate and scale?</p>
<p>Click on one of the squares</p>

<svg height="600px" width="600px">
  <g id="main" transform="translate(25,25) scale(0.25)"></g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem with the zoom function itself. I would suggest zooming the children as opposed to the parent if that would work

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom",function(){
  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale;
  svg.selectAll("rect").attr("transform","translate("+t[0]+","+t[1]+") scale("+s+")")  
}).scaleExtent([1,10]);
```

**EDIT**

The problem with the above code is that d3.js does not register the transformation or initial state of the SVG. This problem runs deeper. As `d3` does not keep track of the SVG transformations and just executes them. It only keeps track of transformations you've run on the library in a variable called `__chart__`.

So when the zoom function is run it just interpolates the variables and gives the output. As no functions have been run on this yet the `__chart__` variable has not been set and causing the jerky start from (x=0, y=0, k=1).

Solution:

1. Run this code before the zoom transformation to set the initial chart manually

   ```
   svg.transition().each(function(){
       this.__chart__={x:25,y:25,k:0.25}; //or you can pick those values using attr
    });
   ```
2. Zoom the svg programmatically to 25,25,0.25 first before any other function. (this is why your workaround works as the `__chart__` variable gets set)

Comment: True, that fixes this specific example, but not the general case. I need to look at how d3 sets up the tweens for zoom transitions--specifically, how it tracks initial state. My workaround for now is to call zoom.event(selection) prior to zoom.event(transition), which seems to set initial state.

Comment: Dug into d3 cause I was curious and came up with the actual answer and the reason your workaround works

Answer (score 1):

To set the initial value of the zoom, try something like this:

```js
// Init zoom
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            });

// Get SVG element
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .call(zoom)
  .append("g");

// Create circle
svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",0)
  .attr("cy",0)
  .attr("r", 5);

// Create init value
var scale = 5;
var translate = [50, 50];

// Set init value
zoom.scale(scale);
zoom.translate(translate);

// Call zoom event
svg.call(zoom.event); 
// or svg.transition().call(zoom.event);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg height="100px" width="100px"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this, but it seems D3 has already evolved a couple of versions.

Although [Majkl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837684/1067465) and [cjds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582515/1067465)'s answers helped me solve my problem, I thought it would help to leave more up to date information, since it was hard finding v5.4 examples out there, until I found [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/) at least.

```js
// Applies event transformation to the Group element's attribute
const zoom_action = () => g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)

// Create the zoom handler
const zoom = d3
        .zoom()
        .on("zoom", zoom_action)

// Get SVG element and apply zoom behaviour
var svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .call(zoom)

// Create Group that will be zoomed
var g = svg.append("g")

// Create circle
g.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",0)
  .attr("cy",0)
  .attr("r", 5)

// Set initial scale and translation
zoom.scaleBy(svg, 5)
zoom.translateBy(svg, 50, 50)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>

<svg height="100px" width="100px"></svg>
```